# After pointing Cpanel domain to Shopify, I am not able to either Receive or Send Emails

Tags: shopify, cpanel

I've recently pointed my domain to Shopify and set up my store there. However, I quickly noticed that I'm unable to send or receive emails. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't found a solution yet. If you've encountered similar issues in the past, I would greatly appreciate any advice or solutions you can offer. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the DNS settings of your domain for sending or recieving email or you can also use services like Cloudflare

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).